# Azure APP Service average response time is more than 100 times than the service instance running in Localhost and in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-rest-api

I have recently published my ASP **.Net core (5.0) API** database being used is **Azure SQL Database** as Azure App service. But while testing Api calls and their response time, I found something very strange. Azure App service response time is much higher compared to localhost running Api.

I am new to azure app service so if anybody could give me some insight on this what's going on.

I am adding app insights of api hosted in Azure and response time while running its locally

Azure Response:
[image]

Postman response :
[image]

Localhost response:

[image]

Update :

Both azure service and Azure Sql server in same resource group and in same region (Central US)

Comment: Look at the dependencies tab in App Insights, how long is the call to the database taking? are app service and database in the same azure region?

Comment: @DylanMorley For testing your point, I created both Azure service and Azure SQL server in same resource group and in same region but still response time is very high and much of the time being used in Sql transaction/calling to database only - Its almost taking **300 ms** for a simple query.

Comment: Your Request endpoint is saying 5.35 seconds average, and your database response is saying 300ms. Where do you think the rest of the time is being spent? You're spending 5 seconds doing something, which is a long time - you should answer that before worrying about the 300ms query time. 

Check your connection pooling - are you spending time opening/closing the connection to SQL? Use your telemetry to help you understand where the time is spent, add additional logging if need be

Comment: @DylanMorley After moving SQL server and following Jason Pan solution I set minimum Logging level to Error and now Average response time is about **400** ms so there is drastic improvement but still difference is noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Dylan Morley's comment is useful, please follow his suggestion to investigate this issue.

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

1. Create a very simple api to test and check the response time.

   If the response time is about the same, then it can be considered that the problem is not related to the App Service.

   If the difference is large, [please check the logging level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629996/azure-app-service-very-slow-reponse-from-simple-endpoint).
2. Please add additional log in your code to check where the is time is spent.